# Como ligar perfil SOpt com o careers?

Tags: suporte

Como posso ligar o meu perfil do careers com o SOpt? vi alguns perfis onde o tinham feito, segue um exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Você ajusta isso nas [configurações do seu perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/11443). Lá tem um grupo "outros perfis", onde você associa o perfil do Careers e escolhe (num checkbox) se o link deve ser exibido publicamente:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]