# Empregos e imprimir perfil PDF

Tags: debate, stackoverflow

Tenho duas dúvidas sobre o stackoverflow português.

A primeira é que tenho meu perfil no stackoverflow en e lá consigo ver vagas de emprego internacionais e já encontrei empresas inclusive brasileiras anunciando lá, já no pt não encontro no menu superior o link de 'jobs'.

A segunda dúvida é em relação a impressão pdf da aba 'Developer Story', uma função muito boa e legal onde você consegue imprimir tudo relacionado ao seu perfil no stack.

Gostaria de saber se essas funções realmente não existem no stackoverflow pt, e caso tenha alguma data de previsão para que possemos utilizar essas funções aqui.

Comment: O mais próximo que você consegue do developer story é adicionar o botão dele no seu perfil do sopt. [Como ligar perfil SOpt com o careers?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3812/91)

Comment: A previsão pra termos isso aqui é [de 6 a 8 semanas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)

Comment: Algum local onde posso ver essa informação ?

Comment: Qual informação, @MateusVeloso?

Comment: Perdão, não tinha visto o link, obrigado!

Comment: Mateus Veloso, só pra constar o lin**k** que o @LINQ mandou-lhe é uma piada "interna", como o titulo indica *"Meme: 6 to 8 Weeks"*, desculpe cortar a brincadeira LINQ, mas fiquei com receio de outros usuários levarem a sério.

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento, não prestei atenção no link e apenas nos 6 a 8 semanas e realmente estava acreditando kkk, iria ler realmente assim que chegasse em casa.

Comment: Pois é, eu percebi kkkk xD

Comment: @LINQ não vale fazer isso cara kkkkk a mente está cansada, acreditaria em qualquer coisa.

Comment: eu conheço a piada e acreditei - eita essa vontade de trocar de emprego :'D @GuilhermeNascimento